# Push notification when app is in foreground (using Firebase triggers)

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, eventtrigger

Let's say that there is an update in certain collection and it triggers function that "exports" notification for certain user (token). I have implemented `Firebase Functions` in `JavaScript` for `Firestore Triggers` (`onCreate`, `onUpdate`,...) and it works if app is in background.

I want to send a notification whether the application is running or not...
Can user receive notification (lets say `onUpdate`) if app is in foreground or that feature is not ready yet (since triggers are in beta version)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If depends on whether your message contains a `data` property, a `notification` property, or both.

If the message **only** contains a `notification` property, it'll delivered to your application code if the app is in the foreground, but handled by the system when the app is in the background.

If your message contains a `data` property, it'll always be delivered to your application code. If it *also* contains a notification property, that part will be handled by the system when the app is in the background.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).